# a vector to an upper Triangle matrix by row in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a vector say

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I would like to organize them into the elements into an upper triangle matrix (without considering diagonal elements, they are all zero) **by row**. My goal is to get the following matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    3
[2,]    0    0    4    5
[3,]    0    0    0    6
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

But the following way I do it is to replace the diagonal elements with this vector but assign values by column. For example,

```
b= matrix(0, 4, 4)
b[upper.tri(b, diag=FALSE)]=a
```

it will give me the following matrix

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    4
[2,]    0    0    3    5
[3,]    0    0    0    6
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

The reason is that when R assign values to a matrix, by default, it will assign them by column. I am wondering if there is a simple way to solve my problem without writing a for loop.

I found a similar post before related to my problem but it does not explain assign values to a upper triangle matrix by row:

[creating a triangular matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786795/creating-a-triangular-matrix)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one option

```
b[lower.tri(b, diag=FALSE)] <- a
b <- t(b)
b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    1    2    3
# [2,]    0    0    4    5
# [3,]    0    0    0    6
# [4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Alternatively, reorder `a` as required and assign that into the upper-right triangle:

```
ut <- upper.tri(b, diag=FALSE)
b[ut] <- a[order(row(ut)[ut], col(ut)[ut])]
b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    3
[2,]    0    0    4    5
[3,]    0    0    0    6
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that to fill an ASYMMETRIC matrix you could first fill the upper triangle via the code shown above, then the lower with a DIFFERENT vector (no transpose needed).

```
  c <- c(7,8,9,10,11,12)
  b[lower.tri(b, diag=FALSE)] <- c
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a go at implementing this without lower.tri():

```
matFill <- function(vec,mat_size=4,side='right'){
  if(side=='right'){ ridx=1;cidx=2
  } else if(side=='left'){ ridx=2;cidx=1 }
  
  b <-mat_size #ceiling(length(vec)/2)+1 #matrix size
  idx <- t(combn(1:4, 2))
  #or by hand:
  idx <- matrix(NA,factorial(b)/(factorial(b-2)*factorial(2)),2)
  o <- 0
  for(i in 1:(b-1)){ #i<-2
    idx[(o+1):(o+b-i),1] <- i
    idx[(o+1):(o+b-i),2] <- (i+1):b
    o <- o+b-i
  }
  #fill matrix
  mat <- matrix(0,b,b)
  for(x in 1:length(vec)){
    mat[idx[x,ridx],idx[x,cidx]] <- vec[x]
  }
  return(mat)
}


matFill(1:6)
matFill(1:10,5,'left')
matFill(1:14,6)
```

can't figure out how to determine the size of the matrix using the supplied vector though...