# convert uppertriangular matrix to a symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataframe  with 20 rows where each row is a 10 x 10 upper triangular co-variance matrix with diagonal and I want to convert it to a symmetric 10X10  matrix. I had been following the post: [a vector to an upper Triangle matrix by row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787317/a-vector-to-an-upper-triangle-matrix-by-row-in-r) 
But when I do that it gives me a list instead of matrix.

Also I want to do it recursively for each row and store the resulting 20 matrices in a list. For reproducible example here is a dataframe with 20 rows. Each row is 3x3 uppertriangular matrix with diagonal.

```
g <- data.frame(a=runif(20),b=runif(20),c=runif(20),d=runif(20),e=runif(20),f=runif(20))
g1<-c(g[1,])
g2= matrix(0, 3, 3)
g2[upper.tri(g2, diag=TRUE)]=g1
g2
# list of 9 elements instead of matrix
#[[1]]
 # [1] 0.2625916

 # [[2]]
 # [1] 0

 # [[3]]
 # [1] 0

 # [[4]]
 # [1] 0.6255627

 # [[5]]
 # [1] 0.829801

 # [[6]]
 # [1] 0

 # [[7]]
 # [1] 0.3386346

 # [[8]]
  #[1] 0.9517039

 # [[9]]
 # [1] 0.5886387
```

Comment: In stead of doing recursively, which is a specific programming term, you would probably like to do it in a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the given type of data:

```
g<-data.frame(a=runif(20),b=runif(20),c=runif(20),d=runif(20),e=runif(20),f=runif(20))
```

you need to use function `unlist(...)` to change individual cells in a matrix:

```
> g1<-c(g[1,])
> g2<-matrix(0, 3, 3)
> g2[upper.tri(g2, diag=TRUE)] <- unlist(g1)
> g2
[,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.02287811 0.2938224 0.1224342
[2,] 0.00000000 0.7950484 0.1134449
[3,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.7219712
```

After creating the upper triangle matrix, you can make the matrix symmetric by copying the data from upper triangle matrix elements to lower triangle matrix elements

```
> g2[lower.tri(g2,diag=FALSE)] <- g2[upper.tri(g2,diag=FALSE)]
> g2
[,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.02287811 0.2938224 0.1224342
[2,] 0.29382240 0.7950484 0.1134449
[3,] 0.12243420 0.1134449 0.7219712
```

All the matrices in the original data set can then be combined in a list as follows:

```
symlist = list()
for (i in 1:dim(g)[1]) {
  g2 <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
  g2[upper.tri(g2,diag=TRUE)] <- unlist(g[i,])
  g2[lower.tri(g2,diag=FALSE)] <- g2[upper.tri(g2,diag=FALSE)]

  symlist[[i]] <- g2
}
```

As an example, here is the last matrix in the generated list:

```
> length(symlist)
[1] 20
> symlist[[length(symlist)]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.4224727 0.9737866 0.4250256
[2,] 0.9737866 0.7167033 0.2627082
[3,] 0.4250256 0.2627082 0.7556802
```

Comment: Would it be possible to assign values by row instead of column  after unlisting the entries of the matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

@Heikki's answer only works for 3x3 matrices (given the column-filling)

as a workaround, you can fill the upper triangular part, transpose the temporary matrix (so the upper triangular becomes the correct lower triangular), then fill the upper triangular again:

```
g2[upper.tri(g2, diag=TRUE)] <- unlist(g1)
g2 <- t(g2)
g2[upper.tri(g2, diag=TRUE)] <- unlist(g1)
```

this will work for larger matrices too. Example:

```
X <- matrix(0, k <- 4, k)
X[upper.tri(X, diag=T)] <- 1:(k*(k+1)/2)
X <- t(X)
X[upper.tri(X, diag=T)] <- 1:(k*(k+1)/2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    4    7
[2,]    2    3    5    8
[3,]    4    5    6    9
[4,]    7    8    9   10
```